# Network Scanner | Using Python Scapy and PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, scapy

This may sound stupid, but i dont have a lot of experience with saving data caught in python and sent to postgresql database.

What I am trying to do is using Scapy in python to scan the network for devices. The devices that are getting shown after running the small scapy code, should then be sent to my postgresql database.

Does anyone have tried this before, or have an idea to what can help do this?

I have tried doing some research on it, but cant really find anything that answers my questions..

I have looked into sending data to my database, but they methods i have seen, all have to be done manually and not automatically, when the data is shown in python.

Answer (score 0):

So what you'll have to do are two separate steps: first parse the content of what you're collecting via Scapy, and then send everything to Postgres. I haven't done it on a live capture, but on recorded pcaps. I suppose it should work on live captures as well.

```
from scapy.all import *
import psycopg2


conn = psycopg2.connect(host="localhost", database="trainstation", user="username", password="password", port=5432)

cur=conn.cursor()


files = [list, of, pcaps]


def create_tab():
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE proberequests(id serial primary key, mac text, ssid text, rates integer[], channel integer, esr integer[], ht text);")
    print("Created table")
    conn.commit()
    print("committed everything to db")

def parse_pcap(pcap_path):
    pcap_flow = rdpcap(pcap_path)
    sessions = pcap_flow.sessions()
    counter = 0
    for session in sessions:
        for packet in sessions[session]:
            counter +=1
            try:
                mac = get_mac(packet)
                ssid, rates= get_ssid_and_rates(packet)
                channel = get_ds(packet)
                esr = get_esr(packet)
                ht = get_ht(packet)
                query = "INSERT INTO proberequests(mac, ssid, rates, channel, esr, ht) VALUES('" + mac + "', '" + str(ssid) + "', '" + str(rates) + "', " + str(channel) + ", '" + str(esr) + "', '" + str(ht) + "');"
                cur.execute(query)
            except Exception as e:
                query = "INSERT INTO proberequests(mac, ssid, rates) VALUES('" + mac + "', '" + str(ssid) + "', '" + str(rates)  + "');" # sorry for the messy workaround :X something isn't working with the esr if it's empty 
                cur.execute(query)
                pass
    conn.commit()
    print("Added", counter, "probes to the database")


def get_mac(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(Dot11ProbeReq):
        return str(packet.addr2)
    else:
        return ""


def get_ssid_and_rates(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(Dot11Elt):
        ssid = packet.info.decode('ascii')
        rates= set(packet[Dot11EltRates].rates)
        return ssid, rates
    else:
        return '', {}


def get_ds(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(Dot11EltDSSSet):
        channel = packet[Dot11EltDSSSet].channel
        return channel
    else:
        return 255

def get_ht(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(Dot11EltHTCapabilities):
        return str(packet[Dot11EltHTCapabilities].info)[2:-1]
    else:
        return ''

def get_esr(packet):
    if packet[Dot11EltRates][1]:
        return set(packet[Dot11EltRates][1].rates)
    else:
        return {}

create_tab()

for filename in files:
    print("Adding file" , filename)
    parse_pcap(filename)
```